# Fetch a sigleton nested singleton resource in Emberjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to fetch a singleton resource which has the following route: `/api/users/:user_id/profile`. The user model knows nothing about the profile. The models are defined as follows in Rails:

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

How can I define EmberJS models and routes so that if i go to `/users/1/profile` it fetches the profile of the user? I've been trying to find out how to define singleton resources in EmberJS but could not find anything suitable.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [DS.belongsTo](http://emberjs.com/api/data/#method_belongsTo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "the user knows nothing about the profile", do you mean that the API response for `/api/users/:user_id` doesn't include any reference to `/api/users/:user_id/profile`? If so, you can always *tell* Ember it does.

Assuming JSON-API:

```
// serializer:user
normalize(type, hash, prop) {
  const result = this._super(type, hash ,prop);
  const userId = result.data.id;
  result.relationships.userProfile = {
    links: { related: `/api/users/${userId}/profile` }
  };
  return result;
}
```

Or if you're on an older Ember-Data:

```
// serializer:user
normalizeRelationships(type, hash) {
  hash.links = hash.links || {};
  hash.links.userProfile = `/api/users/${userId}/profile`;
  return this._super(type, hash);
}
```

Then, the `model:user` can have a `userProfile` relationship:

```
// model:user
userProfile: DS.belongsTo('userProfile', { async: true })
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! That makes sense. I had some concerns since ember js is not quite good at handling singleton resources.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need an adapter, something like:

**adapters/user-profile.js**

```
import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';

export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/users',
  pathForType() {
    return 'user_profile';
  },

  urlForFindRecord(id, modelName) {
    return this.urlForFindAll(modelName);
  },

  urlForUpdateRecord(id, modelName) {
    return this.urlForFindAll(modelName);
  }
});
```